# Spring integration kafka inbound adapter aggregating incoming messages

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I have a `int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter` which I am using to send messages to kafka and then receiving messages using a `int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter`. Communication seems to work fine, I am able to send and receive messages but the format is a bit strange. I am sending individual messages separately to my outbound adapter but when I receive the messages, I get one message back with all messages aggregated into the payload of that one message.

This is how the message payload looks like when I receive the messages

> [payload={mytopic={0=[string message 1, string message 2, string message 3, string message 4, string message 5, ...........]}}, headers={id=3934de02-1f42-ab90-6aa5-9c15f3cd0b6e, timestamp=1439260669762}]

Receive integration flow looks like this

```
<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaInboundAdapter" kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext"
    auto-startup="true" channel="inputFromKafka">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="10" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"
        max-messages-per-poll="5" />
</int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="inputFromKafka" />

<int:service-activator id="kakfaMessageHandler"
    input-channel="inputFromKafka">
    <bean class="com...broker.MessageHandler"></bean>
</int:service-activator>
```

Any reason why I am receiving all messages aggregated in one spring integration message instead of separate messages as they were sent to kafka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KafkaHighLevelConsumerMessageSource` is designed as many other polling `MessageSource<?>`: to get the data by the one poll and return it as a `List<?>`.

In this case we have this result from Kafka `stream` reading:

```
Message<Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Object>>>>
```

where the `payload` is a `Map` of Kafka `topic`s and maps of `partition`s and `message`s there.

If you use only one `topic` on the `consumerContext` you can simply transform the top-level `Map` just to its `partition`s map. Or even go ahead and transform just to the `payload`s list, if you have only one `partition` there. and finally you can end up with the `splitter`.

If you'd like to receive messages from the topic one by one plus as quickly as they appear there, you should take a look to the `<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter>`.